# Настройка сети с помощью сервиса network

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я новичок в Linux Ubuntu, пытаюсь понять как настроить сеть при помощи сервис network. Возникла такая загвоздка, при вводе в терминале команды service networking start возникает ошибка что не находит networking.service. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так. (код из книги которую я читаю)[image]

Comment: Или эта команда действует только при управлении локальной сети, но не на глобальную?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что этот сервис вообще должен быть?

Comment: Раньше был в стандартной поставке. Через него поднимался lo   раньше

Comment: @eri использование команды service вместо systemctl намекает, что это видимо было примерно во времена мамонтов)

Comment: Тем не менее в 22.04 ifupdown ещё присутствовал. Вроде...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно его установить https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=networking.service&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any

Файл    Пакеты
/lib/systemd/system/networking.service  ifupdown, ifupdown-ng

Comment: Подозреваю, что NetworkManager будет возмущаться

Comment: Нет, они сосуществовали больше 10 лет вместе и ничего)  в nm даже можно включить поддержку управления

Comment: Спасибо, сегодня попробую сделать.

Comment: Я то-то совсем не понял, как пользоваться командами ifupdown, ifupdown-ng. И для эти команды, нет ни справочной информации для них в терминале?

Comment: Это не команды, это два варианта пакета. 'man interfaces'

Comment: Всё понятно. Я то по ссылке перешёл, но не придал значения, что это пакеты.